# Make multiple instances of Laravel Echo for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, laravel-echo

i'm trying to add `websockets` in flutter application using this package: [laravel_echo: ^0.2.9](https://github.com/kakajansh/echo).

I have Notifications and Messages in my application, so if i create `websocket` for only of the two it works fine. However if i add the second `websocket` they all stop working.

#### Code snipet:

*pusher_socket.dart*

```
class PusherSocket {
  
   Echo socket({ String authToken }){

        PusherAuth _auth = PusherAuth(
          'https://api.example.com/broadcasting/auth',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': '$authToken',
          },
        );
        

      PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
        host: "api.example.com",
        port: 6003,
        encrypted: true,
        auth: _auth,
        cluster: "CLT",
      );

      FlutterPusher pusher = FlutterPusher("MY_KEY", options, enableLogging: false );

      return new Echo({
        'broadcaster': 'pusher',
        'client': pusher,
      });
  }
}
```

#### Listening in a page

*NB: I want to use this code in different pages*

```
Echo echo = new PusherSocket().socket(authToken: conversationProvider.authToken);

echo
    .join("conversation.${conversationProvider.conversation.id}")
    .listen('NewMessage', (data) {
    print(data);
    try {
        final message = data;

        Message _message = Message.fromJson(message);

        conversationProvider.addMessage(message: _message);
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
});
```

### Is there anything that i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you do not neet to creat two instances of `websockets` for that. You can creat a global `websocket` then use it across the application.

#### Example.

here i have instantiated `websocket` inside `AuthProvider` because i know the `AuthProvider` will be included in the root of the application, making it available to all sub `Widgets`:

*pusher_socket.dart*

```
class PusherSocket {
  
   Echo socket({ String authToken }){

        PusherAuth _auth = PusherAuth(
          'https://api.example.com/broadcasting/auth',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': '$authToken',
          },
        );
        

      PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
        host: "api.example.com",
        port: 6003,
        encrypted: true,
        auth: _auth,
        cluster: "CLT",
      );

      FlutterPusher pusher = FlutterPusher("MY_KEY", options, enableLogging: false );

      return new Echo({
        'broadcaster': 'pusher',
        'client': pusher,
      });
  }
}
```

*auth_provider.dart*

```
class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String authToken;
  Echo echo;

  
  Future<void> sigin({@required email, @required password}) async {

      /**
       * the logic for login
       * goes here
       */

      // Set echo if not set
      if (echo == null && authToken != null) {
        echo = PusherSocket().socket(authToken: authToken);
        print("Prepare echo");
      }

      //notify others
      notifyListeners();
  }
```

*conversation_page.dart*

```
final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);

authProvider.echo
    .join("conversation.${conversationProvider.conversation.id}")
    .listen('NewMessage', (data) {
    print(data);
    try {
        final message = data;

        Message _message = Message.fromJson(message);

        conversationProvider.addMessage(message: _message);
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
});
```